# Execute an function after ending the function before

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to know, what's the best way to realisation that in Swift 2 in xCode:
How can I execute the second function after ending the first function, and then function number 3, then 4. And so on?

Edit:

What do you mean about this resolution?

```
// Function 1
func function_1(completion: (result: Bool)->())
{
    // Wait 10 sec
    sleep(10)

    print("Function 1")

    completion(result: true)
}

// Function 2
func function_2(completion: (result: Bool)->())
{

    print("Function 2")

    completion(result: true)
}
```

To call:

```
function_1()
{ (boolValue) -> () in
    if boolValue == true
    {
        self.function_2()
        { (boolValue) -> () in
            if boolValue == true
            {
                // function 3
                print("and now function 3")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to execute the second function "after ending" the first one? Why not just execute it as the last step in the first function? More information is needed to make this question clear.

Comment: Hi. Because, for example,  I need the same functions in different tasks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 2 functions `func0` and `func1`, you must add to the param of `func0` a closure having the same signature of `func1`.

```
func func0(completion: () -> ()) {
    defer { completion() }
    print("func0")
}

func func1() {
    print("func1")
}
```

Now simply call them writing

```
func0 { func1() }
```

**Output**

```
// func0
// func1
```

Repeat the same technique for more functions.

Comment: What do you mean about this resolution?